# How to add apostrophe (") to string?

Tags: escaping, autoit

I have this AutoIt script:

```
ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1")
Sleep(500)
ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
Sleep(500)
ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1")
```

It types a file name inside a file selection window. I want to add `"` before and after my string (the string I send as command line argument to my script).

I tried `ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1] & """)` but this results into error: `Unterminated string.`.

Comment: Looks like Autoit acts like many such languages, and uses double quotes to represent a single one inside a string. E.g., """" should resolve to a single quote in a string. That is, if the first hit on a quick google search is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Autoit uses pairs quotes to indicate a single instance within a string.

E.g., `""""` (notice, there are 4 double quotation marks) acts as a single double-quote within the string.

So `$CmdLine[1] & """"` should add a single double-quote.

See AutoIt's documentation. https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm has a section on strings.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt supports two types of quoting, which are interchangeable:

```
MsgBox(0, "single-double", 'hello " world')   ; hello " world
MsgBox(0, "double-single", "hello ' world")   ; hello ' world
MsgBox(0, "double-double", "hello "" world")  ; hello " world
MsgBox(0, "single-single", 'hello '' world')  ; hello ' world
```

I personally prefer the first two (depending on how my string looks like).

So one of those should do:

```
ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1] & '"') ; Changing quoting where needed
ControlSetText('Open', '', 'Edit1', $CmdLine[1] & '"') ; Changing quoting consistent
```

Answer (score -1):

> I tried `ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", $CmdLine[1] & """)` but this results into error: `Unterminated string.`.

No attempt to add double quote *before* `$CmdLine[1]` was made (only after).

> I want to add `"` before and after my string …

As per [Documentation - Intro - Datatypes - Strings](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_datatypes.htm):

> If you want a string to actually contain a double-quote use it twice …
> You can also use single-quotes …

1. ### Double double-quote

   As per [Documentation - FAQ - 3. Why do I get errors when I try and use double quotes (") ?](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3):

   > If you want to use double-quotes inside a string then you must "double them up". So for every one quote you want you should use two. …

   - `"` becomes:

     `$sString = """"`
   - `This is a "quoted" string.` becomes:

     `$sString = "This is a ""quoted"" string."`.
2. ### Single quote

   As per [Documentation - FAQ - 3. Why do I get errors when I try and use double quotes (") ?](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3):

   > … or use single quotes instead: …

   - `"` becomes:

     `$sString = '"'`
   - `This is a "quoted" string.` becomes:

     `$sString = 'This is a "quoted" string.'`.
3. ### ASCII code

   As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `Chr()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Chr.htm) :

   > Returns a character corresponding to an ASCII code.

   - `"` becomes:

     `$sString = Chr(34)`
   - 34 is [the `"` -sign's ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), so `This is a "quoted" string.` becomes:

     `$sString = "This is a " & Chr(34) & "quoted" & Chr(34) & " string."`
   - Or per [`StringFormat()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringFormat.htm) :

     `$sString = StringFormat("This is a %squoted%s string.", Chr(34), Chr(34))`

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).